# How can I include price filter logic in a React filter?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on multi filter checkbox in react and redux. How to add extra price filter logic when:

1. The price range is less than 250
2. The price range is between 251 and 450
3. The price range is greater than 450

Below is the code for the filter reducer. Tried this if else condition but the problem is if multiple checkboxes are clicked this doesn't work

```
case actionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCT:
      const searchParameters = data && Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));
      let filterData;
      console.log('test',action.payload);
      const searchQuery = action.payload.map((val) => val.toLowerCase());
      const getItemParam = (item, parameter) =>
        (item[parameter] ?? "").toString().toLowerCase();

      if (action.payload.length === 0) {
        filterData = state.products;
      } 
      else if(action.payload.includes('0-Rs250')){
        filterData = state.products.filter((item) => {
          return item.price <= 250
        })
      }
      else if(action.payload.includes('Rs251-450')){
        data = state.products.filter((item) => {
          return item.price > 250 && item.price <= 450
        })

      }else if(action.payload.includes('Rs 450')){
        filterData = state.products.filter((item) => {
          return item.price > 450
        })
      }
      else {
        filterData = state.products.filter((item) => {
          return searchParameters.some((parameter) => {
            const itemParam = getItemParam(item, parameter);

            return searchQuery.some(
              (color) => itemParam === color)
          });
        });
      }
      console.log('test1',filterData);
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredData: filterData,
      };
```

Comment: Is the `filterData` contains the price value?

Comment: searchQuery contains the price value and i need to replace itemParam === color with the corresponding filter logic for each price range

Comment: hi, I tried logic to add prices ranges, you can check it, if it ok or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the conditions from *exclusive OR* to *inclusive OR* by changing from `if - else if - else` to `if - if - if`.

Example:

Start with initially empty filtered result set, and for each filtering criteria filter ***and append*** the original `state.products` array.

```js
case actionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCT:
  ...

  let filteredData = [];

  ...

  if (action.payload.length) {
    if (action.payload.includes("0-Rs250")) {
      filteredData.push(...state.products.filter((item) => {
        return item.price <= 250;
      }));
    }
    if (action.payload.includes("Rs251-450")) {
      filteredData.push(...state.products.filter((item) => {
        return item.price > 250 && item.price <= 450;
      }));
    }
    if (action.payload.includes("Rs 450")) {
      filteredData.push(...state.products.filter((item) => {
        return item.price > 450;
      }));
    }
  } else {
    filteredData = state.products.filter(/* filter by searchParams */);
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    filteredData,
  };
```

An alternative using a more inline solution:

```js
case actionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCT:
  ...

  const filteredData = state.products.filter((item) => {
    if (action.payload.length) {
      return (
        (action.payload.includes("0-Rs250") && item.price <= 250) ||
        (action.payload.includes("Rs251-450") &&
          item.price > 250 &&
          item.price <= 450) ||
        (action.payload.includes("Rs 450") && item.price > 450)
      );
    }
    return /* filter by searchParams */;
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    filteredData,
  };
```

This second method retains the original order of products from the source array.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this logic for prices ranges like this:

(here I used normal `price` to explain how to add this logic, you can use your own `value` instead of this `price`)

```
...
else {
     filterData = state.products.filter((item) => {
       return searchParameters.some((parameter) => {
          const itemParam = getItemParam(item, parameter);
          return searchQuery.some(
          (price) => price < 250 && (price > 251 && 
            price < 450) && price > 450) 
       });
   });
}
...
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: This will not work as i have to filter data with price range

Comment: I have edited my question for more info

Comment: Do you have any codesandbox example or can you reproduce for it?

Comment: As You said, `if multiple checkboxes are clicked this doesn't work` it means multiple checkboxes clicking are not working?